# VC++ Equivalent of typdef void* in VB6

Tags: visual-c++, vb6

I have a vc++ dll which has a funciton call like this :

```
 typedef void * SIS_HANDLE;
 EXTERN_C SDK4OpenDevice (SIS_HANDLE* sDev );
```

Now am trying to call the VC++ dll in VB6 is there any equivalent for the same in VB6.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's a pointer-sized integer, which is `Long` in VB6.  And your function takes a pointer to a pointer, so it will be `ByRef`.

```
Declare Sub SDK4OpenDevice(ByRef sDev As Long);
```

Watch out for the calling convention though, if that `EXTERN_C` macro doesn't hide a `__stdcall` or `__pascal` keyword, the function can't be called from VB6 directly.

Comment: Thanks ben, One more query if you dont mind What if my VC++ code returns the pointer like this : 
SIS_HANDLE WINAPI SDK4OpenDevice (const char *portName,int baud,int parity,int receiveTotalTimeout); how should i cast the same in VB6

Comment: It depends what SIS_HANDLE is. If it's a 32-bit then `Long` again is your best option. VB6 is strongly typed but not as widely as C++.

Comment: @Deanna: The question tells us what `SIS_HANDLE` is -- a pointer, and all VB6 programs are 32-bit, so a pointer is always the same size as VB6 `Long`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the type itself was a pointer rather than just the parameter.